# Why am I getting Index out of bounds here?

Tags: solidity, arrays, solidity-0.8.x

I am trying this:

```
address[][] memory mintQuantity = new address[][](2);
mintQuantity[0][0] = address(0);
mintQuantity[1][0] = address(0);
```

But keep getting an error:

```
[FAIL. Reason: Index out of bounds]
```

I have tried multiple variations of new `address[][](2)` but can't seem to get it right.

Doing this with a One-Dimensional Array works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The `new address[][](2)` is allocating an array for two `address[]` but it is not allocating the `address[]`.

```
address[][] memory mintQuantity = new address[][](2);
mintQuantity[0] = new address[](3);
mintQuantity[1] = new address[](5);
mintQuantity[0][0] = address(0);
mintQuantity[1][0] = address(0);
```

Comment: Thank you! What exactly does the (3) in address[](3) mean? 

My understanding is an address[] with 3 possible values passed as a constructor for the Type?

Comment: @Alex It is the array length. The syntax `new Type[](N)` allocates an array of `Type` with `N` elements.